# SAT - penetration and pull out vector based on previous body position

Tags: separating-axis-theorem

I implemented SAT alghorithm that is able to detect collisions and return shortest "pull out" vector.
On the screenshot below this vector is determined by yellow color (P and Q).
If I add Q vector to position of body B, then will be no collision.

However I realized that I can't use this vector to solve collisions, because the body could arrive from completely different direction. I should rather pull out body B by using direction of vector Z.

I already tried to calculate additional overlap by using axis determined by vector Z. However in such case I'm pulling body B too far away from A.

Is there any ellegant solution for that by keep using SAT algorithm?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think I found an answer for my question by using SAT algorithm only.
Of course I'm completely ignoring tunneling effects.

Let's say we have shapes A and B. Shape B penetrated shape A.
We know old position of shape B (before the collision).
We already did some collision test (SAT) and we know that the collision between shapes A and B exists.
Let's draw an axis P determined by old and new position of shape B.

[image]

Now project all vertices of shapes A and B on axis P.

[image]

Now we can move shape B by using vector Z calculated by formula:
Z = UNIT(P) * (Amax - Bmin)

Where UNIT(P) is unit vector of axis P.

[image]

The collision has been removed, because now we have at least one separating axis.
However, we are not ready yet. Shape B is too far away from A.
We need to snap shape B to A on axis P.

Let's repeat SAT test, but this time we are looking for gaps.

[image]

We found a gap on axis Q. The length of the gap can be calculated easily.
We also know the angle between P and Q and we can calculate snap vector S.

Now we can add vectors Z (initial pull out) and S (snap).

Answer (score 1):

Likely not as elegant as you're hoping for, unfortunately.

SAT is primarily for collision detection between two convex shapes, not collision response. So you're already down a bit of a rabbit-hole. You could implement a sweep test (rectangle-rectangle-sweeptest in this case) to help you identify the optimal response to the collision. i.e. point, direction, and duration of the collision.

Something like what's shown here - http://supertux.lethargik.org/wiki/Sweep_collision_algorithms

I wish I had a better answer for you, kudos for using SAT though! :)

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I found a solution of using SAT only, however I ignored tunelling effects. I will need to use some kind of sweeptest anyway :)